# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, though the file exists

Tags: node.js, line-by-line

This is my project structure:

[image]

This is `index.js`.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var links = require('../models/Links');

var readline = require('linebyline');
var rl = readline('../data.txt');
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

    rl.on('line', function (line, lineCount, byteCount) {
        var data = line.split(',');
        var id = data[0];
        var url = data[1];           
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried rewriting

```
var rl = readline('/../data.txt');
var rl = readline(__dirname +'/../data.txt');
```

Nothing works.

Comment: `ENOENT` is usually permissions. Does your application have the permission to access the file?

Comment: also, you should call `readline` right before `rl.on('line')`...

Comment: it was doing fine until i moved the code in index file. The code was in app.js file and worked fine.

Comment: @NickBull yes, everyone has read&write permission to that file

Comment: @cviejo did that, problem exists :(

Comment: that was unrelated to the problem. it's just that the way your code looks now you won't be getting any lines (even after fixing the problem)

Comment: @cviejo understood! thanks for the tip

Comment: called readline right before rl.on('line') and changed to var rl = readline('./data.txt'); , now working!

Answer (score 8):

Your readline invocation is still going to be relative to the directory your app is running in (your root, where app.js resides), so I don't think you need the parent directory reference.

It should be just

```
var rl = readline('./data.txt');
```

Or if you want to use __dirname

```
var rl = readline(__dirname + '/data.txt');
```

Comment: thanks , figured that. i had to call readline right before rl.on('line')  too

Comment: Makes sense, although that's not what was causing the error in question: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, though the file exists